# Matlab: efficient matching of row and column indices in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, matching

I want to create a logical `n-by-n` matrix `A` based on two `n-by-1` index-vectors `a` and `b`, such that the `(i,j)`-th element in `A` is `1` if and only if `a(i)==b(j)`.

One way to do this is as follows:

```
  a = [1 1 2 3]';
  b = [2 3 1 3]';
  n = 4;

  a_mat = repmat(a, [1 n]);
  b_mat = repmat(b', [n 1]);

  A = a_mat == b_mat;
```

The problem with this approach is that it becomes quite memory-intensive if `n` is large. I am looking for a more efficient approach that does not require creating huge `a_mat` and `b_mat` matrices and is also reasonable fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the matlab's implicite expension (require matlab R2016b or newer)

You can simply write:

```
A = a==b.';
```

**BENCHMARK**

```
  n = 20000;
  a = randi([1,100],1,n)';
  b = randi([1,100],1,n)';
  A = zeros(n,'logical');

  % Solution 1
  tic
  a_mat = repmat(a, [1 n]);
  b_mat = repmat(b', [n 1]);

  A = a_mat == b_mat;
  toc

  % Solution 2
  tic
  A = bsxfun(@eq, a, b');
  toc

  % Solution 3
  tic
  A = a==b';
  toc

Elapsed time is 24.357663 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.497311 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.120866 seconds.
```

In terms of memory usage, solution 2 and 3 should be quite similar. You can also sparse you matrix once your computation are done with `sparse(A)` in order to reduce the size of your matrix A.

Comment: Good to know, I was wondering whether implicit expansion works. Unfortunately I'm still stuck with 2016a for now...

Answer (score 0):

ok, just found the answer myself, it's actually rather trivial (not sure whether to leave or just delete the question?):

```
    A = bsxfun(@eq, a, b');
```

Comment: Not sure either. But you should replace `'` by `.'` in case the values are complex

Comment: it's only indices (natural numbers) in my case, but generally, yes! (although in that case one should probably specify some tolerance for the matching)